# 2 unconfirmed transactions after 24hrs

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, multibit

Hey guys been looking through the forums and I'm still not quite sure how to speed things up or fix it. (Not very good with this kind of stuff)

Here's my wallet address - 1GZK3NYHCAScGRb4awAkXGVXszstwCVEEh

Both transactions say they have been seen by 50+ peers

I used the standard multi bit classic fee 0.0001
Which has never slowed me down in the past.

Any advice or help would be awesome

I'm happy to just get them back and send again with a higher fee.

Cheers

Edit: I'm using multibit classic. I have done a block chain reset. One of the transactions says it's in my balalnce (not spendable) and the other seems to have stayed the same (being sent to the same address) but has only had the peers reset. I've looked on blockchain info etc just not really understanding what I'm looking at. I assume the problem was the low fee, which I've now changed in my settings. Just not sure how to get it all back and start again.

Sorry I'm a bit of a noob

Answer (score 0):

Do you own the wallet in your computer or is it in the clouds (p.ex., Blockchain)? If so, what is the version, model (Blockchain.info, Bitcoin.org core 0.140.)?
.
For now, **export your wallet and encrypt it!**
Also, check these steps: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41972/47329

> Why is it taking so long for my transaction to confirm?
>
> If you have sent a transaction
>
> without (or with an **exceptionally small) transaction fee**
>
> expect it to be ignored for an unknown amount of time until a miner decides >to process it and solves the block; this could be several days to several weeks, **possibly never**. Your wallet and any Bitcoin node will show it as unconfirmed, your transaction is stuck in limbo.
>
> Block sizes are limited, which means that only a limited number of transactions can be processed in a certain timeframe. In the beginning of bitcoin, there was lots of free space in each block because there were not many transactions. However, now that Bitcoin is quite popular there are more transactions than can be processed into the current block. This is why transaction fees have increased, and as long as someone is still willing to pay more they will keep increasing.
>
> What can I do to speed-up the transaction’s confirmation?
>
> **Nothing. The next best thing is to cancel and resend the transaction.**
>
> 1. Make a note of the individual bitcoin address(es) that the unconfirmed transaction was sent from.
> 2. Run Bitcoin Core with the -zapwallettxes option (or wait a few days until your wallet stops broadcasting the transaction and it falls out of the global transaction mempool)
> 3. **Send all your bitcoins from the addresses recorded in step 1 to a new address with the recommended or higher than recommended fee.**
> 4. Make original transaction again using the recommended fee

Comment: Which fee should I use?

The fastest and cheapest transaction fee is currently 220 satoshis/byte
For the median transaction size of 226 bytes, this results in a fee of **49,720 satoshis.**
- https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

Comment: I'm using multi bit classic on my laptop. Before you answered I did a reset on my blockchain. But nothing has seemed to have happened. I have upped the standard fee to max for when I'm ready to send. I'm just not sure how get them back into my wallet. At the moment 1 of the 2 transactions says it's back in my balance, but it isn't spendable. And the other is still listed as going to its original destination (peers have reset though).